# Why React MUI component class name does not match with css classes?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I would like to ask help for understanding MUI.

I am using React MUI (a.k.a. `@mui`) with this SSR example: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/eba90da5359ff9c58b02800dfe468dc6c0b95bd2/examples/material-express-ssr

My understanding is that when an HTML tag has a class property it can be used as selector in CSS. Like `<div class='foo'></div>` and `.foo { color: 'red' }`. Although when I download my SSR page I can see many values in the class property and only a single one (last one) matches the CSS selectors (see attached picture).

**What are the other class properties and how they are used (or why they are not)?** - Eg.: `foo-bar-MuiButtonBase-root`

Can I separate the MUI styles and states as styles and add incrementally on any HTML tag later?
[image]